# What rules would i create for 2 rows of .col?

Tags: html, css, rows, multiple-columns

I am attempting to make 2 rows of `.column` elements in my html document. Right now I have 1 row of columns followed by another row below it in the footer.

The first row of columns seems to do what I want, but when I tried to create another row of columns with the same rules, it aligns vertically instead of horizontally. How would I change the CSS to make the 2nd row of columns function like the first row?

Here is HTML:

```
<div id="columns">
  <div class="left column">
    <p>left column</p>
  </div>

  <div class="middle column">
    <p>middle column.</p>
  </div>    

  <div class="right column">
    <p>right column.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <div class="left column">
    <p>left column</p>
  </div>

  <div class="middle column">
    <p>middle column.</p>
  </div>    

  <div class="right column">
    <p>right column.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
#columns {
width: 960px;
padding-top: 50px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#columns .column {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 1%;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}

#columns .left {
    float: left;
}

#columns .middle {
    float: left;
}
#columns .right {
    float: right;
}
#container #col1 {
    width: 320px;
    float: left;
}
```

This is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cj6dj/)

Comment: so you want a layout of 6 columns across?

Comment: In css you are not referring to footer div at all and there are 2 `</div>`'s missing.

Comment: 3 columns across, 2 rows. I have the </divs> in my document I will edit my example

Comment: what would the CSS look like to incorporate the footer?

Comment: with your code [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cj6dj/) is what I see. Is this incorrect?

Comment: create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your code

Comment: correct eric, that is what it looks like

Comment: @mattmahan that looks like 3 columns, 2 rows. Whats wrong?

Comment: I must have mispoke. I meant 3 acorss 2 down. there is 3 down and 2 across in that example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given what it sounds like you're asking for, I believe you're wanting to create the following:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
|     left column    |   middle column    |    right column    |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|     left column    |   middle column    |    right column    |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

In order to do this, you actually don't need nearly as complex a system as you've created. You can simply do the following:

```
<div id="container">

    <div class="column">left column</div>
    <div class="column">middle column</div>    
    <div class="column">right column</div>

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="column">left column</div>
        <div class="column">middle column</div>    
        <div class="column">right column</div>
    </div>

</div>​
```

Then for CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 960px;  /* Provides a container with width = 3 columns + 2 paddings */
    padding: 30px; /* Provides left, right, top and bottom padding of 30px */
    margin: 0;     /* No margin around the bounding box */
}

#container .column {
    border: solid 1px #000; /* The border you were using */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* This forces width/height specs to set the size of 
                               the column's edge, INCLUDING border/padding */
    float: left;            /* Allows each column element to stack left */
    padding: 1%;            /* Provides the padding you wanted */
    width: 300px;           /* Sets a width */
}
```

I've noted within the CSS why each piece is important.

The key, though, is the property `box-sizing: border-box;`. Without this, the borders and padding being added to the `.column` elements would actually make them `300px` + `1%` + `2px` (`1px` left, `1px` right) - which makes the 3 columns much wider than you're wanting. By applying `box-sizing: border-box;` it forces the `.column` elements to fit the `1%` padding AND the `solid 1px #000` border *inside* the specified `300px` width.

In other words - 3 columns of `300px` actually = `900px`. When you then add on the `30px` left and right within the `#container` it still fits within the `#container`'s `960px` width.

You can see all of this at work in [my update to your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/Cj6dj/1/)

Comment: Thank you tony, exactly what I wanted to create. one thing though when i use this code the padding does not create space in between the boxes

Comment: Yes - that's true. If you want to add some spacing, I suggest dropping the `width: 300px;` to `width: 296px;`, and then adding `margin: 2px;` to the `#container .column {}` section. This will create `4px` of padding between the boxes, and `2px` of padding between the outer edges and your container. [Here is an update that shows this](http://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/Cj6dj/2/)